# Blackbox: GPG decrypt fails (don't know ctb=00)

Tags: gnupg, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm using [Blackbox](https://github.com/StackExchange/blackbox) to protect sensitive files in my repositories, but suddenly, inexplicably to me, it simply stopped working.

I am running a GitLab CI deployment script, and the `blackbox_postdeploy` fails with message `gpg: [don't know] ctb=00`.

I've been able to find out that `ctb=00` usually has to do with corrupt keychains, but since I'm running this on a clean Docker-container (through the GitLab CI) I don't know how to fix it.

Here's the output from the GitLab CI script:

```
$ gpg -v --import <(echo "$GPG_PRIVATE_KEY")
gpg: directory `/root/.gnupg' created
gpg: new configuration file `/root/.gnupg/gpg.conf' created
gpg: WARNING: options in `/root/.gnupg/gpg.conf' are not yet active during this run
gpg: keyring `/root/.gnupg/secring.gpg' created
gpg: keyring `/root/.gnupg/pubring.gpg' created
gpg: pub  4096R/ABC1234 2017-04-28  Bot <bot@redacted.com>
gpg: /root/.gnupg/trustdb.gpg: trustdb created
gpg: using PGP trust model
gpg: key ABC1234: public key "Bot <bot@redacted.com>" imported
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1  (RSA: 1)
$ which ssh-agent || ( apt-get update -y && apt-get install openssh-client -y )
/usr/bin/ssh-agent
$ eval $(ssh-agent -s)
Agent pid 72
$ ssh-add <(echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY")
Identity added: /dev/fd/63 (rsa w/o comment)
$ mkdir -p ~/.ssh
$ [[ -f /.dockerenv ]] && echo "$SSH_SERVER_HOSTKEYS" > ~/.ssh/known_hosts
$ git config --global url."git@gitlab.com:".insteadOf "https://gitlab.com/"
$ ln -s /builds /go/src/gitlab.com
$ cd /go/src/gitlab.com/me/mysystem
$ blackbox_postdeploy
========== Importing keychain: START
gpg: [don't know]: invalid packet (ctb=00)
gpg: key export failed: invalid packet
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

Things I've tried:

- Manually removing Blackbox files.
- Forcefully re-initializing Blackbox in the repository.
- Re-creating the public key for my deploy bot.
- Removing the `/root/.gnupg`-folder on the container before deploying.

Can anyone help me along here? This is occasionally breaking my repositories, being a huge pain for my development process.

Thank you.

Comment: I too was stuck on this and have recently solved it. Are you using `gpg2`?

Comment: Hey! Thanks for answering. Yeah, I think we're using GPG2.

Comment: Great. So there were a couple of things I did. Hopefully you are able to edit your script files. 

In the file `_blackbox_common.sh` I edited `${GPG:=gpg}" ;` to `${GPG:=gpg2}" ;` (around line 26). I also edited `function get_pubring_path()` to `echo "${KEYRINGDIR}/pubring.kbx"`. Then I edited `function prepare_keychain()` on the line starting with `$GPG --export ...` and the line below it, I replaced with `$GPG --keyring "$(get_pubring_path)" --export | $GPG --import`. 

TL:DR. [`_blackbox_common.sh`](https://gist.github.com/gurpreet-/6e58947136a0e6c6001729143a40a33e)

Comment: If the above works for you then I can write it up as an answer.

Comment: Hmm, cool solution, and good edits to the commons file! However, I have microservices, which means I'd have to implement that file in a bunch of different repos, or otherwise be able to replace it, which is tricky for me. I think maybe downgrading to GPG1 would be more suitable, I'll have to check. Thing is, it was working, and suddenly just stopped...

Comment: You could package it as a .deb file and install it. Make the edits above then follow the instructions listed [here](https://github.com/StackExchange/blackbox#installation-instructions). Assuming that your microservices run in a ubuntu container/OS then the bullet point `The Debian/Ubuntu way` will help you (i.e install `fpm` and then run `make packages-deb`). This should package it up as a deb file. Then when your microservices startup, just do `dpkg -i <the_deb_file>.deb` which should install it to `/usr/bin` with all the edited changes.

Comment: @gurpreet- I used your solution and it worked for me, thank you.

Comment: @gurpreet - thanks! Here is blackbox-fork implementing your patch https://github.com/mipmip/blackbox Hope to submit a more sophisticated PR soon.

You can write it as an answer

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to only use gpg2 when both are installed.

```
$ gpg2 -v --import <(echo "$GPG_PRIVATE_KEY")
```

The problems have been fixed in blackbox HEAD. Pull the latest blackbox version and call blackbox commands with an environment variable.

```
$ GPG=gpg2 blackbox_deploy
```